# Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance even when mp.Manager.Queue() is used

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

as shown in the below posted code, i use map_async as shown in method `startProcessing(self)`.when the execution of the code enters the if-statement in the code in section labeled `code-1` the `getResults` method should be called
and blocks waiting for all processes to finish. the problem i am facing is that despite `run(self,params)` method returns list, an invocation to `proc.get()` causes the app to crash and generates the error message posted below.

please let me know why i am getting this error message and how to solve it

**code1-instantiation of an object**

```
NDVIsPer10mX10mForNoneKeyWindowQueue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()  
areasOfCoveragePerNoneKeyWindowQueue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()   

noneKeyGridCellsProcessingPool = NoneKeyGridCellsProcessingPool(
NDVIsPer10mX10mForNoneKeyWindowQueue, 
areasOfCoveragePerNoneKeyWindowQueue,  

ndviTIFFDetails.getNDVIValuePer10mX10m(),
pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt,
fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG25832,
[]
)
noneKeyGridCellsProcessingPool.startProcessing()

if (noneKeyWindowCnt > 0):
    '''close pools: do not accept or allow any new tasks/jobs'''
    resultsForNoneKeyGridCellsProcessingPool = NoneKeyGridCellsProcessingPool.getResults() #<====generates the error message posted below 
    NoneKeyGridCellsProcessingPool.closePool()
```

**code in class NoneKeyGridCellsProcessingPool**

```
@staticmethod
def getResults():
    for proc in NoneKeyGridCellsProcessingPool.procs:
        proc.get() #<====generates the error message posted below 
    last = MiscUtils.getElementFromArrayForIndex(NoneKeyGridCellsProcessingPool.procs,len(NoneKeyGridCellsProcessingPool.procs) - 1)
    return last.get()
    
def __init__(
    self,
    
    NDVIsPer10mX10mForNoneKeyWindowQueue:Queue, 
    areasOfCoveragePerNoneKeyWindowQueue:Queue, 
    
    NDVIValuePer10mX10m,
    pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt,
    fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG25832,
    fourCornersOfNoneKeyWindowInEPSG4326
    ):
    super().__init__()
    
    self.params = (
        NDVIsPer10mX10mForNoneKeyWindowQueue, 
        areasOfCoveragePerNoneKeyWindowQueue, 
        
        NDVIValuePer10mX10m,
        pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt,
        fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG25832,
        fourCornersOfNoneKeyWindowInEPSG4326
    )
    self.res = None

def run(self,params):
    self.NDVIsPer10mX10mForNoneKeyWindowQueue = params[0] 
    self.areasOfCoveragePerNoneKeyWindowQueue = params[1]
    
    NDVIValuePer10mX10m = params[2]
    pixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt = params[3]
    fourCornersOfWindowInEPSG25832 = params[4]
    fourCornersOfNoneKeyWindowInEPSG4326 = params[5]
    ....
    ....
    ....
    return self.NDVIsPer10mX10mForNoneKeyWindowQueue,self.areasOfCoveragePerNoneKeyWindowQueue
    
def startProcessing(self):
    self.res = NoneKeyGridCellsProcessingPool.pool.map_async(self.run, [self.params])
    NoneKeyGridCellsProcessingPool.procs.append(self.res)
```

**error msg**:

```
File "C:\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 359, in assert_spawning
raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

**note:**

```
i am returning a list as shown in the code in the class NoneKeyGridCellsProcessingPool, but .get() method as in `proc.get()` seems sees the returned values as a queue??!!
```

**1st_update**

to solve this issue, i commented the return statment in class `NoneKeyGridCellsProcessingPool` out, and replaced it with `return 'ok'`, however, i got the same error message

Comment: Good instruction in the title.

Comment: What was the question please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell oh,sorry i forgot to add descriptive text to the problem..i will do it now

Comment: @MarkSetchell i posted some text descriping the problem

Comment: Include the full definition of `NoneKeyGridCellsProcessingPool`. It's likely that after instantiation, one of the instance attributes is a queue, or an object which contains a queue, which is what is causing this issue.

Comment: @Charchit i added an update to the question in a sectioon labeled 1st_update..would you  please have a look?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass or return a `multiprocessing.Queue` to or from a child process. Either the queue should already be available in the parent process, in which case you can simply read from it. Otherwise you must pass an actual list or tuple rather than a multiprocessing queue.

The following is an example that produces a similar stack trace. Given you have said that the types of the queues you are not returning are not `multiprocessing.Queue`. It is reasonable to assume one of the parameters contains a `multiprocessing.Queue` (or is one). You'll need to figure out which. Maybe try dummy jobs that just takes and return its argument, once for each separate parameter. NB. `self` is passed as an implicit parameter to when you do `pool.map_async(self.run, ...)`

```py
import multiprocessing

def main():
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

        # The given queue is not allowed to be passed as an argument,
        # but no error is raised by the following line.
        future = pool.apply_async(dummy_job, [queue])

        # Instead, the error is raised here. If the queue is changed to
        # an instance of Manager.Queue then no error will be raised.
        result = future.get()

        print(result)

def dummy_job(arg):
    return 'foo'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thought

Comment: thank, but could you please point precisely where i am returning a queue in my code? i am returning a list, isn't it?i meanin in      return self.NDVIsPer10mX10mForNoneKeyWindowQueue,self.areasOfCoveragePerNoneKeyWindowQueue

Comment: Those variables are type annotated as `Queue`, they have "queue" in their name, and similarly named variables are instantiated as Queues in your instantiation snippet. Why do you think they are lists? There's no evidence in your code to suggest that they are lists. But yes, the return statement of the `run()` method is where you are returning queues.

Comment: Yes but this does not really answer the question of why queues *created through* managers could not be passed to/from pool workers, as the OP seems to be unsuccessfully doing

Comment: @Charchit, Ah yes, that was an oversight on my part. The error refers to a `multiprocessing.Queue` being passed about. `Manager.Queue` should be fine. Seems like some objects are not what they appear in this code. Just noticed that `NoneKeyGridCellsProcessingPool.procs` has methods called `append()` and get()`, which is mixing and matching list and queue interfaces.

Comment: would you please have a look at the section 1st_update?it is an update to the question i added it

Comment: In this scenario, is really helps to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code isn't reproducible or complete. No one else can run your code and get the same error. It's also not minimal. There are a lot of extra parameters, to which the types are not known. So it's just a guessing game. However, I did manage to produce an MRE that gives the same error message. You will need to check it matches your situation though.

Comment: @Dunes thanks, would you please tell me the difference between instantiating a pool using with-keyword and instantiating it in the ordinary way of instantiating my object e.g: o = mp.pool(…)?